# Is it possible to collect sensor data using AsyncTask?

Tags: android

Suppose I am trying to collect data from sensors at a high rate, and write it to a file. The collection is controlled from the UI by "start" and "stop" buttons. Does it make any sense to write a class like this:

```
protected class DataLogger extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements SensorEventListener
```

of should I be using threads directly?  Empirically, I find that using `AsyncTask` like this locks up my UI, but I can't quite put my finger on why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a good idea to me, because `AsyncTask` objects normally have a limited lifespan. They do their task and then they go away. Who will listen to your sensors when that happens? A `Service` seems a much better choice for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

BlackRider seems to be quite right.  It turns out that a much better way to collect sensor data is as follows:

```
Sensor Manager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("sensorThread");
mHandlerThread.start();
handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);
```